# How to remove port number from url?

Tags: tomcat, proxy, port

My application "XY" running on port 1234 in tomcat server. I'm using HA-Proxy for loadbalancing. So in loadbalancing my front end port is 5678 to access the "XY" application through browser. Right now, I'm accessing htp://abc.game.com:5678/index.html. I want to access the same url but without port number. Because every time I've to remember port number to access application. How I can achieve this? There are multiple applications running in similar way, and same way it is configured haproxy.conf(centos 6)

Comment: Have a look at the right, "related" -->

Answer (score 0):

For achieving this you will have to use mod_jk connector to connect Apache with Tomcat. This will serve your pages without showing port number.

For CentOS you can follow these steps:

```
# cd /var/java/

# mkdir mod-jk

# wget http://www.eu.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-connectors/jk/tomcat-connectors-1.2.41-src.tar.gz

# tar -xf tomcat-connectors-1.2.41-src.tar.gz

# yum install -y httpd-devel gcc gcc-c++ make libtool
# cd tomcat-connectors-1.2.41-src/native
# ./configure --with-apxs=/usr/sbin/apxs
# make
# libtool --finish /usr/lib64/httpd/modules
# make install
```

Comment: Thanks,
What will be the next procedure after installing mod_jk?
How to connect or configure it?

Comment: You are welcome. Please follow my this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33551523/centos-with-plesk11-x/33553218#33553218 and if you still have any problem let me know

Comment: Are you still facing problems or fixed?

Comment: Let me know if you want to configure it as well or faced any problem